# Python - how to get a list of all global names I have ever defined?

Tags: python

I work in a python shell and some weeks ago I have defined a variable which refers to a very important list. The shell stays always open, but I have forgotten this name. How to get a list of all global names I have ever defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the globals or just the user-defined ones?

```
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> x=2
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'x': 2, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

To get the things you have defined yourself, it appears that you can filter out from this list all key-value pairs whose keys do not match the regex `"__.*?__$"`.

**UPDATE**

Here is a better answer:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun  5 2011, 15:52:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 3
>>> import re
>>> [name for name in dir() if not re.match(r'__.*?__$', name)]
['re', 'x']
```

Here I've excluded the special names beginning and ending with two underscores, so if you used them yourself they will not show.  The `$` at the end of the regex to prevent accepting `__abc__1`.  Also I switched to `dir()` which gets symbols in the current scope, not necessarily the global one, but it seems cleaner.  It doesn't add the leading list comprehension variable like `globals()` does.

Comment: @psihodelia Right, edited the answer.  I can add the code to filter the dictionary if you like.

Comment: Just saw that.  Commented on one of the answers.

Comment: @psihodelia Added the filtering rule to this answer also, just in case anyone lands here first.

Answer (score 6):

Use `dir()`

For example,

```
>>> x = 666
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'x']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can examine `globals()`, which shows all the module-level variables, or `locals()`, which is the local scope.  In the prompt, these are the same.  Also, `vars()` shows all the names available to you, no matter where you are.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you have `readline` enabled? You can look through your interpreter history to find what you want. I think it's easier than digging through `globals()` or `dir()`.